# Offset and limit not working with sql server and codeigntier

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

Am using codeigniter 2.2.x version of codeigniter with sql server 2014 and 2008.Will offset and limit work properly?Is this an issue ?

```
function get_data($limit, $offset) {
$ss_db = $this -> load -> database('billing', TRUE);

$ss_db -> select('stuff, stuff2, stuff3');
$ss_db -> from('mytable');
$ss_db -> limit($limit, $offset);
$this -> db -> order_by("id", "asc");
$r = $ss_db -> get();

return $r;
```

}

Will this work for pagination and all other queries using limit and offset together

Output: Am getting output like top 5 rows,top 10 rows,top 15 rows etc.I cannot do like 0 to 5,5 to 10, 10 to 15 etc

Comment: What is the error or output??

Comment: output am getting like top 5 rows,top 10 rows, 20..etc..if limit is 5

Comment: I don't use codeigniter, but I do notice that everything for the select statement uses `$ss_db->` but `order_by()` uses `$this->db->`. Now they may be the same, but it does look inconsistent?

Comment: $this->db-> thing is working fine, i would like to know whether codeigniter works with limit and offset combination in any way.

Comment: try to print query using this function `echo $this->db->last_query();` and check the query is proper or not

Comment: The query is proper but, the result is am getting all rows from beginning eventhough am using offset.